# Laravel Spotify gives error - even when following Github

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, spotify

So I'm using this package: https://github.com/aerni/laravel-spotify for a project, and I've followed the "Usage-steps", but I keep getting this error:

> Non-static method Aerni\Spotify\Spotify::searchTracks() should not be called statically

when I do it the way the package says.

This is my code:

```
public function index()
{
    $variable = Spotify::searchTracks('Wish You Were Here')->get();
    dd($variable);

    return view('pages.index');
}
```

with

> use Aerni\Spotify\Spotify;

on top of the file. Because of the error I tried this:

```
(new Spotify)->searchTracks('Wish You Were Here')->get();
```

but I get this error:

> Too few arguments to function Aerni\Spotify\Spotify::__construct(), 0 passed in C:\ProjectDirectory\hetplatenhuis-newversion\app\Http\Controllers\Pages\IndexController.php on line 13 and exactly 1 expected

Is there anyone who has experience with this package?

Comment: The example on that page uses `use Spotify;` though, have you tried this instead of `use Aerni\Spotify\Spotify;`?

Comment: thanks for your reply lol. I tried it, but got this error instead: Call to a member function getBody() on null

Comment: No clue, `getBody()` sounds like a method from guzzle, some request most likely failed